# Stopping form submission on page refresh

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a form with Flask/Python/Html

When the form is submitted it is routed to another page where it gives a confirmation such as "Form submission success!"

However if I refresh the page it will submit the content again, so I potentially could end up with duplicate data.

Is there a way to prevent this?

HTML

```
<form action="{{ url_for('submitForm') }}" method="post">
<input name='user_input'>
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Python/Flask

```
app.route('/submitForm', methods=['POST'])
def submitForm():
    data = request.form['user_input']
    some_list.append(data)
    return 'Form submitted'
```

Comment: This is why it's normal practice to redirect on the server-side after successful form submission. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the browser stores the state of the last request, so if you refresh the page at this point the browser will re-submit the form.

After handling a successful form request, redirect to the page to get a fresh state.

something like code below

```
return redirect(url_for('submitForm'))
```

hence

```
app.route('/submitForm', methods=['POST'])
def submitForm():
    data = request.form['user_input']
    some_list.append(data)

    print('data submitted successfuly')
    return redirect(url_for('submitForm'))
    return 'Form submitted'
```

Comment: Do you use ajax/jquery. That could also be an option where a form input is emptied immediately after submission via ajax. An subsequent submission will fail as long as you validated the form for emptiness

Comment: Thank you @Nancy very much, I was having some issues with form submission too due to forgetting to ```redirect``` after the function was done.